# error on php exact search with multiple options

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'd like to create "Exact Search" with multiple options but the answer says "Could not search".

In the table, price, one and pre are rows.
If the answer matches one and pre, the separated price will be come out. If not, the reply will be "Try agian".

Edited : I have three tables - pre, one and price.

```
- KA 1 will win 100
- KA 5 will win 500
- MA 3 will win 100
- MA 1 will win 200
- BA 3 will win 800
```

Edited : I changed the code now and no error shown but the result was always 'Try Again'.

```
    <?php
    $output = NULL;

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","searchdemo") or die("Unable to select database" . mysqli_error($link));

    if(isset($_GET['search'])){
        $searchq = $_GET['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

        $query = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM `345` WHERE pre = '$searchq' AND one = '$searchq'") or die("<b>Error</b> : ".mysqli_error($link));
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);


if ($count == 0){
    $output = 'Try Again';

}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $onen = $row['one'];
        $pren = $row['pre'];
        $price = $row['price'];

        $output = 'You won '.$price.' now';
    }

}
}     
?>

        <form name="search1" action="index.php" method="GET">

        <b>Prefix</b>
                <select name="pre">
                <option value="">Pick a prefix</option>
                <option value="Ka">Ka</option>
                <option value="Ba">Ba</option>
                <option value="Ma">Ma</option>
        </select>
        <b>Number</b>
                <select name="one">
                <option value="">Pick a number</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />

        </form>

        <?php
        print ("$output");
        //echo ($output);
        ?>
```

Comment: Please look into using `MySQLi` or `PDO` queries as mySQL isdeprecated and no longer supported as well as being full of holes and security flaws. search Google and/or Stackoverflow for guides to upgrade your SQL interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer and that was so easy. What a dumb I am! :)

I do really thanks to @Martin and @jedrzej.kurylo

```
    <?php
    $output = NULL;

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","searchdemo") or die("Unable to select database" . mysqli_error($link));

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        $spre = $_POST['pre'];
        $sone = $_POST['one'];

        $query = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM `345` WHERE pre = '$spre' AND one = '$sone'") or die("<b>Error</b> : ".mysqli_error($link));
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);


if ($count == 0){

    $output = 'Try Again';


}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        extract($row);

        $onen = $row['one'];
        $pren = $row['pre'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $id = $row['id'];

        $output = 'You won '.$price.' now';
    }

}
}
?>

        <form name="search1" action="index.php" method="POST">


       <b>Prefix</b>
                <select name="pre">
                <option value="">Pick a prefix</option>
                <option value="Ka">Ka</option>
                <option value="Ba">Ba</option>
                <option value="Ma">Ma</option>
                </select>

        <b>Number</b>
                <select name="one">
                <option value="">Pick a number</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>

                <input type="submit" name="search" value="SEARCHING" />

        </form>

        <?php
        print ("$output <br />");
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If **die()** is called, it means that the query failed, so I'd start looking for a reason there.

You are missing **WHERE** in your query, it should start with

```
SELECT * FROM 345 WHERE ...
```

Keep in mind that your code is open for SQL injecion attack. You must to escape all user input that gets into your query.

Simplest way to do it is to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php (deprecated since PHP 5.5) or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php. You could also use PDO prepared statements for your queries (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: 345 from `SELECT * FROM 345 WHERE ...` is db table name and can you edit to complete the desired code, please?

Comment: Not sure I understand :) I know it is db table name. I pointed out one error in your query, fix that, check if it works, and if there are some other issues please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some general pointers for you here:

- You need a WHERE clause in your SQL statement to define the criteria of your search. The search will work without it but it will return everything, which is not what you want. (This has already been fixed)
- You need a `AND` or an `OR` statement between your variables, in your WHERE clause, because you are asking *"show this WHERE condition1 is true AND/OR condition2 is true"*
- Replace your `die` command with a better and more informative feedback:
  This will output why the search failed. Use this to fix further errors.

  `or die("Could not search: ".mysql_error());`
- As mentioned by jedrzej.kurylo, you are wide open for injection attacks on your database and it is very important to fix these, either as they suggest or by upgrading your code to using ***MySQLi*** or ***PDO*** . Do this now while you're still learning the basics of SQL because it's far better than getting into the bad habit of using old, deprecated and insecure MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for your information, Martin. I'd already changed my codes but i had error for changes.

Comment: @SiThu I'm pleased to see you updated your code to MySQLi.

Comment: I've changed the code and no error occurred but the answer is always 'Try Again'.

Comment: @SiThu when it says "try again" also print out your value for `$searchq` , because your preg_replace function string looks suspect, to me. I think the preg_replace is incorrect.

Comment: Can u fix this for the result?

Comment: shall I do your job for you? I can only do that if you pay me :-p . Add a `mysql_error` to your SQL code, and check your `preg_replace` . YOU do it, and you will learn from it, if I do it, I will not learn from it as I already know, and you will not learn from it.....

Comment: Well @Martin, I'm just trying to put **personal lottery search** into a website. But I have no idea to do and no time left :) . Lottery has 6 digits and one character like _AA 123456_. I like to let them search by only with **choosing multiple options**. If i need to buy the code, I'd like to offer with little amount. :P